# how to display the value of an array using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I have an array n i have a four buttons n I just want to display array values ,if i click on first button ,first value should be displayed ,click on second button ,second value should be displayed n so on using addEventListener event handler but there is a problem  when i click it directly display last value?

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.box1');
var city = document.querySelector('#name');
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var i = 0;
        var places = ['San diago,USA', 'chicago,USA', 'phoenix,USA', 'New york,USA'];
        while (i <places.length) {
            console.log(city.innerHTML = places[i]);
            i++;
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We'll help you when you get stuck, but we won't write your code for you.  Give it a try yourself first, please, and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You were iterating over the list of buttons, then inside each handler were also iterating over the full list (using the same variable `i`).  Each button only needs one handler, so you only need one loop.

I moved your "Cities" array outside the function, there's no reason to define it separately inside each handler.

```js
const places = ['San diego,USA', 'chicago,USA', 'phoenix,USA', 'New york,USA'];
let element = document.querySelectorAll('.box1');
let city = document.querySelector('#name');

for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  element[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      city.innerHTML = places[i];
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="box1">One</button>
<button class="box1">Two</button>
<button class="box1">Three</button>
<button class="box1">Four</button>

<div id="name"></div>
```

Take special note of the use of `let i` instead of `var i` inside that `for` loop -- ES6 variables are [scoped differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/3412322); if I had used `var` there then all four events would get the value of `i` *after the loop has run* (so all the buttons would be looking for `places[4]`!). With `let` or `const` the variable is scoped within its block, so the value you want is captured by each iteration in the loop.